# chrome extension - event when extension is removed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, event-listener

Is there any event I can listen to from a Chrome extension when it is removed by the user?

I use Google Analytics to monitor the usage of my extension, and I would like to see if a user removes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't listen to an event (because you were uninstalled), but you can set a page to open when your extension is uninstalled with

`chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL(url, callback)`

Comment: Answer below is more helpful as it help execute some code after we uninstall extension

Comment: @SandeepChikhale How is it more helpful than simply pointing the uninstall url to a page which runs whatever code you want?

Comment: chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL - its callback is not running when we unintsall chrome plugin - there is no way to execute some code using this approach but we can execute some code with setInterval in content.js file - below answer gave me that idea- your answer is also helpful

Comment: @SandeepChikhale The callback runs after the specified url was registered as the page to be loaded after the extension is uninstalled. It is meant for checking if the uninstall url was set successfully, not to contain code to run during uninstallation. You can host whatever web code you want at the specified url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **chrome.tabs.executeScript**
While the extension still installed and send an uninstallation function to one tab. The function will be run after 10 seconds using **setTimeout**.

After 9.7 seconds you need to run **clearTimeout** so your script will never run.

BUT, if the user will uninstall the extension, the first setTimeout will be called, but the second "clearTimeout" will not be called. So the first function (the uninstall function) will be run in average 5 seconds after uninstalling the extension.

Sorry, if it little hard to understand from my English, but try it, it is working, and you can run any script (that do not using chrome API), after the extension uninstalled. (*Edits are welcome*)

Comment: this is an acceptable answer too, Daniel's one is more elegant though

Comment: This solution is more transparent to the user.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it requires permissions, and isn't possible for apps. It is also just inefficient.

Comment: The question was about extensions

Comment: Can you please provide example of this solution?